# Get token value in action

Tags: struts2

I am using token in Struts 2 to prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF).

If I add token in my JSP page, it generate HTML code like:

```
 <input type="hidden" value="token" name="struts.token.name">
 <input type="hidden" value="6AM02LV6P4R9UR5P3LOI62XG87SEQYIT" name="token">
```

I want to get token value in my Action when I submit form?  How I can get it?

Comment: String tokenName = TokenHelper.getTokenName();
   String token = TokenHelper.getToken(tokenName);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```cs
String tokenName = TokenHelper.getTokenName();
String tokenVal = TokenHelper.getToken();
System.out.println("tokenName: " + tokenName + "tokenVal: " + tokenVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to send the token value to the Action from your Client Side to ensure this isn't a CSRF, you can either send it through a form submit, or add the token to your request parameters.

**option 1)** 
This will only work if you are using a s:form element in your jsp page. Include the  tag into the s:form element. This will ensure that your form is submitted with the generated token.

```
<s:form action="ProcessSimpleLogin">
   <s:textfield name="username" label="Username" />
   <s:password name="password" label="Password" />
   <s:token />
   <s:submit value="Login" />
</s:form>
```

**option 2**
Obtain the token number generated by struts through the "s:token" tag, and insert the token value into a js variable:

```
<s:token />
<script>
    var strutsToken = "<s:property value="#session['struts.tokens.token']" />";
</script>
```

Then add that value into the request parameters, using the "struts.token.name" and "token" parameters names. If you are building your paramString via js, it would look something like this:

```
    paramString = paramString + "&struts.token.name=token";
    paramString = paramString + "&token=" + strutsToken;
```

which will generate a parameter string similar to:

```
http://localhost:2000/namespace/action?username=denise&struts.token.name=token&token=6AM02LV6P4R9UR5P3LOI62XG87SEQYIT
```

Your request will be intercepted by the TokenInterceptor, if the given token is equal to the one stored in session, it will execute the action. Keep in mind that you cannot process a request using the same token twice. Actually Token Interceptors will remove the token variable from session parameters after it is used. To run another request you must be sure that a new token is generated on server side.

Hope this works for you!